# If any object of the java abstract class "Number" is equal to zero

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to make a generic function that takes any type of `Number` and conditionally does something if that number is equal to zero. I want anyone to be able to pass it any of the classes that extend [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, or Short)

So far, I've attempted to use `instanceof` to find out what type the number is, then compare it to an equivalent type

```
public static boolean isZero(Number number) {
    if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO.equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Byte) {
        return new Byte((byte) 0).equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Double) {
        return new Double(0).equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Float) {
        return new Float(0).equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Integer) {
        return new Integer(0).equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Long) {
        return new Long(0).equals(number);
    } else if (number instanceof Short) {
        return new Short((short) 0).equals(number);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works, but it is quite long and cumbersome. Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Have you tried number.equals(0); ?

Comment: Yes I have. It reports incorrectly for anything that isn't an Integer.

Comment: @Spotlight: won't work. `BigInteger`s for example compare `false` to non-BigIntegers.

Comment: I would try using `toString`.

Comment: Yes, toString().charAt(0) == '0' could work in many cases - IF one ignores the fact that 0.9999 will also be equal to 0 ... maybe add a little char-iteration and stop at your personal precision-limit

Comment: Using `toString` is a terrible idea. There's no guarantee that a `Number` implementation will override toString to return a numerical representation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do in a general way; "Zero" isn't even guaranteed to be representable by a general `Number` (because you could e.g. design a "PositiveInteger" class that only represents positive numbers and still adheres to the `Number` class spec).

Attempting to convert the value to any other class may cause truncation or rounding, which would invalidate your test, so unfortunately using any method of the `Number` class itself will probably produce incorrect results.

Comment: Or `ComplexNumber`. +1 for no way to do this is the general case.

Comment: Every field has a unit element for addition, i.e. zero. Since numbers generally extend to sets, which support both addition and multiplication, an equal check to zero can always be done. Also arithmetic should have been a part of the Number design in java, regardless of the precision loss. -- Edit: in your example of positive integers, the method "is zero" would simply always return false, which is still well defined.

Comment: *Mathematically* a zero-check can always be done. The question is about how to do it in Java, for which the answer is that the `Number` abstract class alone does not provide enough information.